# What are pragmatic use cases of parallel stream in Java?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream

Beginning from Java-8, we can use parallel stream (java.util.stream package)

As per theory, it is well-known that the Java's parallel stream is suited when operation needs to be executed in parallel, in contrast to (sequential) stream of Java.

Moreover, Parallel stream has bit overhead in managing parallelism and abundance caution is required.

What are practical use cases where it can be used? Also, how it'd outwit cost of parallelism in such practical use cases?

Comment: Parallel stream is prefered when you have lot of data i.e. above 10 lakhs over a normal stream. Secondly, if you have let's say 1000 data then you can go through stream because using the parallel stream, in this case, would create multiple threads internally which inturn outfit cost.

Comment: @NitinBisht don’t expect non-Indian people to know what a lakh is.

Comment: Do you really mean "real time"?  See this definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing.  If you do mean that, then the answer is that you probably DON'T want to use streams in real-time usecases.  The performance is likely to be too unpredictable.

Comment: aside - if it helps others this is what a [Lakh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) is and in a commonly used convention `10lakhs = 1 million`.

Comment: @Holger meh. We're expected to be able to translate between metric and imperial without complaining about it, I say we need to know about lakhs as well :) I wish I had a couple of lakhs in the bank, I'll tell you that.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to fetch a lot of independent data, parallel stream is good. For example, you have a large database application, where multiple applications are fetching there stored data from independent tables or maybe separate databases, parallel stream will be really good. Also, in web environment, request from a user is independent from other users. In that case, parallel stream is also good.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel streams runs operations over stream in parallel mode.
When you want your list/record processing to be fast , as multiple threads are used for processing the data.
Also, there can be case when you want to process the data and output it in any random sequence as processing of data done by multiple threads so sequence can be anything.

`list.parallelStream().forEach(System.out::println);`

Parallel streams use ForkJoinPool for processing as it is a common pool used by JVM that can be very restrictive.
You can control the parallelism level upto a extent, the most efficient way to take parallelism level is acording to the CPU cores, i.e take parallelism level as 
`2*CPU_CORES`

Like that in below example you can control parallelism :

```
    final int parallelism = 10;
    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(parallelism);
    forkJoinPool.submit(() ->
    list.parallelStream().forEach(System.out::println));
```

But be careful using the parallelism , using a large value of parallelism can degrade the performance of the application.